# Need to query the original APK name from the android device

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have some task to do as follows

I have downloaded a third party application named as Seesmic-27.apk
After installing into device the App icon name is Seesmic and /data/app shows this apk name as **com.seesmic-1.apk**

I want to know how this change has happened from original name ****Seesmic-27.apk**** to ****com.seesmic-1.apk****. I need to get the status of Seesmic-27.apk wheter pass or fail so we need to get original apk name from device. Is there any way to extract this name(Seesmic-27.apk) from device ??

Please help

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. apks are renamed to be in accordance with their package name, and the original name is not stored anywhere.